# How to make pycharm ask before auto closing deleted files

Tags: pycharm

Sometimes by mistake I delete some files in terminal which I have them open in pycharm editor. When this happens, pycharm auto-closes all open tabs for those files. Some editors such as gedit and kate keep the deleted or modified files open or ask to reload respectively. How can I do the same in Pycharm?

Comment: Short answer is that it isn't. If you do it from the PyCharm window then sure, otherwise, how will PyCharm know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in PyCharm for this. However, PyCharm keeps track of all the changes to the working directory of your project in its local history (VCS | Local History in the main menu). You can use that to restore accidentally deleted files.